# Why does the motion in this SDL code appear jerky when in windowed mode

Tags: c++, performance, sdl, frame-rate

For some reason the motion of the square appears jolty, when in windowed mode. I'm pretty sure I'm not optimising my code correctly and it's not a driver issue because I've played OpenGL+SDL games in windowed mode before and it's been fine.

Here is the code (updated to include framerate independent motion):

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
const int width = 1600;
const int height = 900;
const int colourDepth = 32;
void initVideo(){
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, colourDepth, SDL_OPENGL|SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER
        |SDL_FULLSCREEN//if I comment this out it lags
        );
    if(!screen){
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("JERKINESS TEST", "");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    initVideo();
    int x;
    SDL_Event event;
    long lastTime = 0;
    while(true){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if(event.type==SDL_KEYDOWN){
                SDL_Quit();
            }
        }
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2i(x, 425);
            glVertex2i(x+50, 425);
            glVertex2i(x+50, 475);
            glVertex2i(x, 475);
        glEnd();
        long elapsedTimeMilis = SDL_GetTicks() - lastTime;
        x+= 1 * (elapsedTimeMilis/(1000/60));
        lastTime=SDL_GetTicks();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You increasing x the same amount in each frame. There is however no guarantee that your frame-rate will be constant. what you should rather do is measure the elapsed time an increment according to how much time has passed. The will mean the square moves the same distance in the same time irrespective of frame rates.

Comment: But Why would being in fullscreen affect that? It doesn't seem like that's what's causing it.

Comment: Not sure but when if fullscreen mode, the framebuffer IS the screenbuffer. When in windowed mode, the framebuffer is an offscreen memory block. An additional stage is then required to composite your window together with screen elements that exist outside of your application.

Comment: I've added a timer, and altered the movement accordingly, however this doesn't seem to fix it. The jolt happens at regular time intervals. (It stops moving for a few ms every half a secondish).

Comment: TRy changing the while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) to if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)). You might want to put in some logic to limit your frame rate to a maximum of 60fps